# How to detect first loading of NPAPI plugin/Extension in firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, npapi

I want to detect first loading of NPAPI plugin/extension.
Which event should i handle in extension/plugin.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question; what do you mean by "first loading"?  And do you want a plugin or an extension? They are not at all the same thing.  NPAPI is plugins, extensions are different.  http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: taxilian thanks for reply. "First loading" means when Chrome/Firefox start. I have created plugin and extension both. event to extension will be fine for me.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, then, and remove the "NPAPI" tag, since this has nothing to do with npapi.  Ask a question about firefox or chrome extensions specifically. As it is currently worded and tagged nobody who knows the answer is likely to see or understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

My requirement is i want inform the NPAPI plugin when browser starts.I am having my extension and NPAPI plugin.

Chrome Solution:

For chrome `background_helper.js` loads only once when new instance of chrome gets started. It will not reload on new page or new window.

Firefox solution:
On Firefox `window.load` gets called when new windows gets opened so i have added code in `window.load` event handler as follows.

```
var Application = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/fuel/application;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.fuelIApplication);

var myExt= {
  onLoad: function() {
    var windowsArray = Application.windows;
    if(windowsArray.length == 1 && gBrowser.browsers.length == 1)
    {
       alert('FireFox started');
    }
  },
};

window.addEventListener('load', myExt.onLoad, false);
```

Here gBrowser is golbal object gBrowser.browsers.length wil give tab count.